# Why is it always YHVH Elohim and not in the reverse order?

Tags: words, names, grammar-dikduk, commentaries

If I'm correct within the Tenach it's always the term Elohim following the term YHVH. You always read verses and phrases stating: 'YHVH Elohim' and never 'Elohim YHVH'. So why is this?

Comment: See the last verse in habakkuk

Comment: Maybe he should look at Joshua 22:22, although it seems to be the case there that אל and אלהים are a combination while יהוה kind of stands on itself. But I could be wrong

Comment: @DoubleAA You’re missing the point it’s not about the way these words are pronounced, but the way they are written. These are just different words no matter how one pronounces them.

Comment: I have no idea what the point of this question is, but there's no way my example isn't at least somewhat relevant.

Answer (score 4):

It's not always like this as Double AA points out.

The reason why you would want to precede them in that order is hinted to by Rashi on the first verse in Bereishis -- Elokim is connected to Judgment and 4-letter Name - to Mercy, and Hashem precedes Mercy to Judgment, hence the names expressing this precedence come in that order.